# Insert leads through API

Tags: api

we are working with a third party company who is going to insert lead directly into our Salesforce org. one way they suggested is web-to-lead so that they can build an API integration which emulates the form and submits leads directly to Salesforce , but we don't want this route as we got web-to-lead associated to Pardot and I believe we can't have it activated in Salesforce at the same time.
They are flexible to send leads to any system (eg: HTTP post ,JSON,XML, SOAP).
They also want me to send URL but I am not sure which URl link to send. 
I am wondering if anyone can help or has any suggestions as I'm not into programming/coding side.
many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not certain how your Web To Lead is set-up via Pardot, but usually there are assignment rules associated with WTL. If they're able to submit to your WTL URL and use a special field that your assignment rules can leverage, I'd expect you'd be able to work around that by putting that assignment rule first, so that your WTL recognizes the lead as coming from that particular 3rd Party, then assigning it to either a queue or along whatever rules you'd like to use.

If that doesn't work for you, then you'd only have a couple different options. One would be a web services integration of some kind where they upsert leads directly into your database. The other would be something along the lines of sending you a CSV file for you to upsert using Dataloader. I somehow doubt you'd want to do anything along the lines of push notifications as I doubt you'd need them in close to real time.

I recommend you check with whomever set-up your Pardot integration to see how it's configured before doing anything further. You can get the WTL URL by creating a WTL form which will have it on it when you generate it.